# What happened to my question

Tags: support, questions

I asked a question last night about having lost a domain controller without a backup, and trying to recover access to my user info.

But I can't find any record of the question at all, nor any indication that it has been moved or deleted.

What happened to it?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I don't see any new question on this list. Normally I should be able to see if you have any deleted or closed/migrated questions.

Looking your [Stack Exchange profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/b8fbb2af-16e2-43a1-b219-b6c626c4fb3a?tab=activity) I also don't see any question you might have asked in the past week.

My guess is that you might have asked it anonymously or that you accidentally logged in with a different OpenID, so its not attributed to this account.

Either way, I can't find your question. But you can try Googling it across the network to see if it pops up anywhere.

Comment: I also did a cross-IP check and while there are two users who use the same IP at times, they don't have that question on their account either.

Comment: Apparently, it never got posted. I recovered the text from a TimeSnapper log, and went back to re-post it.  Strangely, when I hit the "Ask Question" button, there was everything I had entered, just waiting to be posted.

Comment: If you have a modern browser, it'll automatically save a draft of your question using HTML5 local storage, so that's probably why your text was still there.

Comment: I think actually it was rejected because the tag I used (domain-controller) didn't exist, but I didn't see the rejection message and thought it had been posted.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the scenario, removing all those comments